# Difficulty to figure out what (uint8_t const * const *) means in .Net terms

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, porting

I'm reading a C++ code, and I'm pulling my hair trying to understand this cast:

```
(uint8_t const * const *) someVideoFrame->someData
```

I see something like a pointer to an array of byte, but I have difficulties understanding the double `constant pointer` usage.

From what I've been able to understand, I've simply ported it as (byte **).

In terms of steps, what is this cast trying to achieve? What is the `const` effect in C++ ?

**Edit**

I've found this meanwhile in C++ documentation:

```
int const * const Constant4
```

> ... declares that Constant4 is constant pointer to a constant integer. Basically ‘const’ applies to whatever is on its immediate left (other than if there is nothing there in which case it applies to whatever is its immediate right).

But I'm still wondering what is the objective of declaring constants on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from right and move to the left: **pointer** to **const pointer** to **const uint8_t**

```
   uint8_t const     * const           *
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^           ^
//               to               to
// const uint8_t <- const pointer <- pointer
```

If you want to learn more about reading pointer declarations and be as good as it gets, I strongly recommend [learning the "spiral rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Although old, I found it super useful, and the mnemonic is really easy to grasp.

The cast is probably trying to enforce that you're not modifying by mistake the inner pointer (which is `const`), nor the data it points to (which is also `const`).